# Generate random number from the set {1, 3, 100}

Tags: java, random

I already know how to generate a random number within a range;
but my question is about possibility of generating a number from a set of 2 or more specified numbers.
for example:
the output must be randomly chosen between exactly "1" or "3" or "100"

Another way to put it is:  The value obtained will be any of the three numbers: 1, 3 or 100 (without any of the numbers in between).

Comment: How would that work? I don't really see how that's different than 1-100.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, exactly;

Comment: Thanks every one; most of the solution would work

Comment: @AndrewThompson whats the hurry cowboy?!

Comment: There is no 'hurry' about it, but I'd noted A) You were new & B) You addressed that thanks to 'everyone' whereas 'no-one' would have been notified of the new comment. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson you are so kind

Comment: Wow.  I've been called a lot of things recently, and 'kind' surely was *not* one of them.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Put the numbers in an `int[3]`
- Choose a random number between 0 & 2.
- Use that random number as the index of the array.

..is one of many ways.

Comment: simple and true; probably the best, tnx

Comment: Best solution if you want the outcomes with equal probabilities.

Comment: @pjs you dont mean that salihrkc's solution is not? given that the numbers are divided correctly.

Comment: @Shervin4030 salihrkc's solution gives probabilities .33, .33, and .34, i.e., not quite uniformly distributed.  Having said that, if you want unequal probabilities then that answer is one way to do it.  For instance, change the tests to .25 and .25 if you want to get 100 twice as often as the other two outcomes.

Comment: Doh!  Make that .25 and .5 if you want to get 100 twice as often and do it correctly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Random` is your solution for it:

```
public static int generateRandomNumber(int[] availableCollection) {
   Random rand = new Random();
   return availableCollection[rand.nextInt(availableCollection.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {1,3,100}
```

Store them in an array and then select a random element from there. To select random element, see this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081025124826AAR8rmY

Comment: believe me; If I had enough reps; I wouldn't hesitate; sorry

Answer (score 0):

Java `Math.random()` generates random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 you can write a code for what you want.
For example:

```
double random = new Math.random();
random = myRandom(random);

    public double myRandom(double random){

        if(random < 0.33){return 1;}
        else if(random < 0.66) {return 3;}
        else {return 100;}
    }
```